# Bash sed replace double dollar sign $$ extended regular expressions

Tags: sed, regular-expression

This command:

```
echo '$$foo=bar' | sed -E "s/(\$\$foo=).*/\1$(echo hello)/"
```

outputs:

```
$$foo=bar
```

If I change the `sed`'s quotes to single and enclose the command in double quotes:

```
echo '$$foo=bar' | sed -E 's/(\$\$foo=).*/\1'"$(echo hello)"'/'
```

it outputs the desired result:

```
$$foo=hello
```

So I guess the problem lies in the extended regular expressions and quotes, unless I'm missing something obvious.

1. Is concatenating single and double quotes in `sed` command substitution  good practice (`sed 's/foo/'"$(command)"'/'`)?
2. How can I escape double dollar signs in `sed` with extended regular expressions?

Comment: First, you can just surround `$$foo=bar` with singles quotes as in `echo '$$foo=bar'`. That will escape the dollar signs. Second, what is the desired output? First you say that `$$foo=hello` is the desired result but then you state the that substitution goes fine when it outputs `$$hello=bar`. Which one do you want?

Comment: @NasirRiley *but then you state the that substitution goes fine when it outputs $$hello=bar*. It's an example of a substitution with double dollar signs that works.

Comment: *First, you can just surround $$foo=bar with singles quotes as in echo '$$foo=bar'*. You are right.

Comment: What is your desired output? What makes the last one "fine"? You are confusing double quotes with command substitution (`$(foo)`). What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @terdon Sorry if I haven't been clear, but Kusalananda's answer covers my question. I hope reading it will clarify things.

Comment: Ah, no, your edit removing the bit without the command substitution makes it clear. That's what was confusing me, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[POSIX has this to say](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) about the difference in how `$` is interpreted in basic and extended regular expressions:

Basic regular expressions (BREs):

> A `<dollar-sign>` ( `$` ) shall be an anchor when used as the last character of an entire BRE. The implementation may treat a `<dollar-sign>` as an anchor when used as the last character of a subexpression. The `<dollar-sign>` shall anchor the expression (or optionally subexpression) to the end of the string being matched; the `<dollar-sign>` can be said to match the end-of-string following the last character.

Extended regular expressions (EREs):

> A `<dollar-sign>` ( `$` ) outside a bracket expression shall anchor the expression or subexpression it ends to the end of a string; such an expression or subexpression can match only a sequence ending at the last character of a string. For example, the EREs `ef$` and `(ef$)` match `ef` in the string `abcdef`, but fail to match in the string `cdefab`, and the ERE `e$f` is valid, but can never match because the `f` prevents the expression `e$` from matching ending at the last character.

Conclusion: In a BRE, the `$` character matches itself unless it's the last character of the expression or sub-expression (in which case it anchors the (sub-)expression to the end of the line). In an ERE, the `$` character always anchors to the end of the line.

When you use

```
sed -E "s/(\$\$foo=).*/\1$(echo hello)/"
```

your ERE (since you use `-E`) is `($$foo=).*` and this expression will *never* match (the POSIX text above contains the example `e$f` which is similar).

Your command

```
sed "s/\$\$foo/\$\$hello/"
```

uses the BRE `$$foo` which will match the literal string `$$foo` since the `$` characters are not at the end of the expression.

To match a single `$` character in an extended regular expression, use `\$` or `[$]`.  To escape that for the shell in a double quoted string, use `\\\$` (an escaped backslash followed by an escaped dollar sign) or `[\$]`, i.e.,

```
sed -E "s/(\\\$\\\$foo=).*/\1$(echo hello)/"
```

or

```
sed -E "s/([\$][\$]foo=).*/\1$(echo hello)/"
```

(The backslash in `\1` does not need escaping since backslashes only act as an escape character in a double quoted string if followed by a dollar sign, backtick, double quote, another backslash, or a newline; so the `\1` is literal, not an escaped `1`; [reference here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)).

Short answers:

1. You either single quote the bits that need single quoting (and concatenate that with a double quoted string containing your shell expansions), or you escape what needs to be escaped in a single double quoted string.  This is a matter of taste.  I'd be more concerned with using a command substitution in the expression, as that is a code injection vulnerability unless you have full control over the string that is inserted.
2. `\\\$` or `[\$]` in a double quoted string. `\$` or `[$]` in a single quoted string.