# sed command works with e flag but not with E

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a string and I need to add `#`, in the beginning,i.e. convert `[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return` to `#[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return`. I can use below command:

```
echo '[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return'| sed -n -e 's/\[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 \] && return/#&/p'
```

It works. Now I have two questions, regarding `E`, flag.

1. For the string `[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ]`, if I escape brackets, it does not work; however, it works when I do not escape them i.e.

   ```
   sed -n -E 's/[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ]/#&/p'
   ```

   works while

   ```
    sed -n -E 's/\[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 \]/#&/p'
   ```

   doesn't work.
2. For, the full string `[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return`, it gives me wrong answer, when I do not escape them:

   ```
   echo '[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return'| sed -n -E 's/[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return/#&/p'
   ```

   It gives me output:

   ```
    [ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 #] && return
   ```

I want to know how it is working.

Comment: The `[` and `]` must be escaped in both BRE and ERE (otherwise they define a range expression). As to why you get no output when escaping them and using ERE, I think it's a difference in how `$` is treated between BRE and ERE when it's not the final character of a pattern - see for example [Bash sed replace double dollar sign $$ extended regular expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537762/65304)

Comment: sed's `-E` and `-e` options are two completely different and unrelated things.  they are **not** alternate versions of each other.  `-e` tells sed that the next argument is a script to be run.  `-E` tells sed to use extended regular expressions (ERE) instead of sed's default of basic regular expressions (BRE).

Comment: You can drop the "-e", it's only if you have separate expressions. The -E option would work if you escaped the "$"'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -n -E 's/[ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ]/#&/p'
```

Does not work the way you expect it to work, it's more of a coincidence: `[...]` is a collection of characters that match. Inside that collection you have a range `-n` from whitespace (0x20) to `n` (0x6E), which can include `[` (0x5B), depending on your locale settings. So the collection matches the first char. See what happens when you take `#&___` as the replacement... not your intention, I guess?

And that's the reason for your full case to fail: The matching character for the collection is the `]` because it is followed by the rest of the pattern, that's why the `#` is inserted there.

The problem with the extended regular expression is like @steeldriver assumed: The `$` anchors the pattern:

> A  ( '$' ) outside a bracket expression shall anchor the expression or subexpression it ends to the end of a string; such an expression or subexpression can match only a sequence ending at the last character of a string. For example, the EREs "ef$" and "(ef$)" match "ef" in the string "abcdef", but fail to match in the string "cdefab", and the ERE "e$f" is valid, but can never match because the 'f' prevents the expression "e$" from matching ending at the last character.

So in ERE, a literal `$` needs to be escaped, while in BRE it only needs to be escaped when being the last character of the pattern.

Also note that `-e` marks the next argument as a script and is optional if there is only one script, while `-E` is a switch. Dropping `-e` for '-E` only works if there is only one script because it was superfluous anyhow.